# What is the best way to enumerate Windows languages in C#?

Tags: c#, windows, localization

I'm trying to enumerate the list of available/supported languages on a given Windows installation using C# in a full-trust client application.  Best method?

Comment: Try to rephrase this so that it isn't so subjective. Rather than best way - just ask how to enumerate the languages. One person's best could be another's worst.

Comment: When you say 'languages', do you mean cultures, or installed UI translations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CultureInfo[] allCultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.NeutralCultures | CultureTypes.SpecificCultures);
```

Comment: Very slick. Nice to know its that easy.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
 InputLanguageManager.Current.AvailableInputLanguages;
```

?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the set of available languages installed by using WMI and querying the MUILanguages property of the Win32_OperatingSystem class:

```
// There's most likely a better way to do this than using this searcher 
// but it's the most reliable way I've found
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from win32_OperatingSystem");

ManagementObjectCollection osCollection = searcher.Get();

foreach (ManagementBaseObject os in osCollection)
{
    string[] languages = (string[])os.GetPropertyValue("MUILanguages");

    foreach (string language in languages)
    {
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(language);

        Console.WriteLine(culture.EnglishName);
    }

}
```

However the languages you get back from this are in the abbreviated format e.g. `en-US` rather than `English (United States)`. I can't see a way round this to get the full language string other than to use a Dictionary of short codes and full descriptions and look up each language.

Comment: you can get the full name by creating a CultureInfo object from the languagecode and accessing its EnglishName property